# Using static libraries in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, libraries

I am a newbie to iOS development. I am trying to import and use a static library from a private vendor. I imported the library correctly as given in various tutorials ( I added the library in header search path, library search path, added in Linked frameworks and libraries ). But the issue is I do not know how to use them. The ".a" files do not have any headers. Can somebody say how to use them?

I tried importing them like this. But all of them gave file not found error.

```
import "abcdef.a"
import <abcdef.h>
```

Comment: Create "Header" folder in that library and put all class in that will show all classes.

Comment: @Kampai Do you mean create a folder named "Header" in the project and put the .a file inside that? I currently have them under Frameworks folder.

Comment: In Framework folder you have create "Headers" folder and than move all files in that.

Answer (score 2):

1. Remove the import `.a` file (never do so)
2. Add the dependencies in `Build Phases` in the `Link Binary With Libraries`
3. In your app, (not the static lib) u should use the classes from the static lib like them inside your project for example: `#import "MyClass.h"`

Comment: Thank you. I did all the steps that you mentioned. But my problem is I do not what classes are inside the static library and hence I do not know what to import. Is there a way to see the classes from the static library ?

Comment: What did u get from the private vendor?

Comment: I got the ".a" static library files

Comment: No interface?? no headers (`.h`) files?

Comment: No. I just got the .a files

Comment: So U can do nothing with it. Even the xcode can't do anything with it.. :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64637/discussion-between-user1429322-and-gran33).